# What does "undefined symbol: stringread" mean?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, masm, undefined-symbol

I'm working on a big project for my college class.

I put a string/array in the .data section like this:

```
stringread BYTE DUP(STRSIZE)
```

And in main I have:

```
push OFFSET stringread
push esi
call ReadFileLine
pop esi
pop OFFSET stringread
```

But I get this error:

```
undefined symbol: stringread
```

I think my problem is that I didn’t declare the string correctly.

At first I thought maybe I wasn’t allowed to push strings directly onto the stack like that, but I looked at my professor's example code and he had something similar:

```
array DWORD 1,2,3,4,5
```

```
push OFFSET array
```

EDIT: I replaced the declaration with this, which seems to have fixed it:

```
stringread BYTE STRSIZE DUP(?)
```

Comment: Is the definition in the same file as the code that uses it?  Is it inside a comment block or something?  Is it possible there's some zero-width non-ASCII character embedded in one of the lines?

Comment: @PeterSmith yes, no, I doubt it. However, I changed it to `stringread BYTE FILESIZE DUP(?)` and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Oh, yes, your previous line was missing a repeat count for the `dup` operator.  Weird that it would produce that symptom of not defining the symbol.  Was there not even a warning about that line with the old syntax?  I wonder what bytes it assembled to in the output.

Comment: (I mean what bytes it would assemble to in the .data section if you removed the lines that try to reference the symbol so it will assemble.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> stringread BYTE DUP(STRSIZE)
> ```

For MASM this line is syntactically wrong. As a consequence what would normally be considered a label, didn't get recognized that way and so the symbol *stringread* was reported 'undefined' once you used it on the line `push OFFSET stringread` in *main*.
The `DUP` operator needs to be told how many duplications you need. Looking at `DUP(STRSIZE)` it would seem that you erroneously have placed the repeat count between the parenthesis. One solution could be:

```
stringread BYTE STRSIZE DUP(0)
```

> ```
> push OFFSET stringread
> push esi
> call ReadFileLine
> pop esi
> pop OFFSET stringread
> ```

`OFFSET stringread` is a so-called 'immediate' aka just a number. While you can `push` an immediate, you can not `pop` an immediate!
You can remove the pushed value either through

- adding to the stackpointer `add esp, 4`
- or popping to a register that you can scratch, like eg. `pop edx`